# How to get the bearer token from keycloak SSO request?

Tags: java, spring, single-sign-on, keycloak

I want my users being able to sign in on a `keycloak` authorization server with single sign on:

```
<a href="http://localhost:8180/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code
       &scope=openid&client_id=myclient&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbookings">SSO</a>
```

After the login, the user is successfully redirected to `localhost:8080/bookings`. Works fine.

Now I want to send a sub http request **in behalf of the user** from my backend as soon as the secured `/bookings` is accessed.

Question: how can I fetch the `Bearer token` from the single sign on action the user just made?

I tried reading the cookies, but they don't contain any useful data.

```
@Controller
public class BookingControler {
    @GetMapping("/bookings")
    public String bookings(Model model, HttpServletRequest req) {
        Arrays.stream(req.getCookies()).forEach(cookie -> System.out.println(cookie.getName() + ": " + cookie.getValue()));
       
       //TODO
       //externalWebService.fetchBookings(bearerToken);

        return "bookings";
    }
}
```

So how can I intercept the "result" of the sign on?
Or as an alternative, let the user click another button in frontend that sends the bearer token to my backend, so I can fetch data from external service on behalf of the user?